# How many kilometers is the distance between OCI availability domains in Frankfurt Region?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm searching for the phisical distance between the three Availability Domain belonging to OCI's Frankfurt Region.
I looked for this information in OCI doc (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/regions.htm), but I found only Regions specs. Does someone know where I can find more specs regarding Availability Domains, in particular Frankfurt OCI Availability Domains?

Answer (score 0):

The locations as not disclosed for security reasons. Any number you could get is not official.

If you need that number for compliance reasons, you should use different regions if
you need to meet any formal number.

Empiraclly, you could test the latency between instances on different ADs, make several assumptions and estimate the "network distance". Some points to consider if you want to experiment that:

- ADs are not equi-distant
- there's no minimum distance. But have in mind that they should be physically independent, so depending on what is needed for that to be achieved, that is the minimum.
- there's is a maximum distance. Some applications require a minimum latency. to offer that, ADs cannot be like 100KM apart.
- The AD name in your tenancy are randomized. AD1 for your tenancy may not be AD1 for another customer. Different tenancies might give different results given the combinations.